# Cast a Collection of <T> by T.class

Tags: java, casting

I am using a method returns object casted as per sent Class.

```
// Student student = (Student) get(Student.class, 19L);
Student student = get(Student.class, 19L); // Working fine

public <T> T get(Class<T> clazz, Long id) {
    Object object = hibernateTemplate.get(clazz, id);
    return Primitives.wrap(clazz).cast(object);
}
```

But what for the Collection ?
I want to invoke a method that always return casted List as my passed Class like this... from the method below.

```
List<Student> list =  get(Student.class); // Error

public List<?> get(Class clazz) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(clazz);
    List<?> list = hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
    return ????; // What should I return from here ?
}
```

What needs to return in the last method ?

Comment: wouldn't you want to return list?

Answer (score 3):

```
public <T> List<T> get(Class<T> clazz) {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(clazz);
    List<T> list = (List<T>)hibernateTemplate.findByCriteria(criteria);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if it explained what you changed, and why.  Also, that cast is unsafe, which the compiler will tell you if you enable all warnings.

Comment: I am using <MODEL> instead of <T>. Is this produce any problem ?

Comment: @M.A.Khomeni. You can use any name!